# WPNeo Stripe connect does not work

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to use Stripe connect with Woocommerce plugin but its not showing on checkout page.

It gives following message:

Sorry, it seems that there are no available payment methods for your state. Please contact us if you require assistance or wish to make alternate arrangements.

SSL certificate is installed on website and test mode is enabled. I tried other payment methods and that works fine.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After debugging the plugin and settings, I found that there was an error in the plugin itself and causing Stripe connect not to work.